WebView2's ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler callback is never called when the process is running in a login screen
I need to use the WebView2 control from a custom credential provider, written in C++. I'm using MSFT's Win32_GettingStarted sample as a test. I can build it in VS 2022 and it runs fine in a regular user desktop.
But if I use the same code from a custom credential provider (that runs in a secure desktop in the login screen) the WebView2 control remains blank. I did some investigation and was able to see that in the following test code snippet:
void CreateWebView(HWND hWnd)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    WCHAR buff[256];

    //Get temp folder
    WCHAR buffTmp[MAX_PATH] = {};
    GetTempPath(_countof(buffTmp), buffTmp);
    StringCchCat(buffTmp, _countof(buffTmp), L"WebView2GettingStarted\\");
    g_strTmpPath = buffTmp;

    // <-- WebView2 sample code starts here -->
    // Step 3 - Create a single WebView within the parent window
    // Locate the browser and set up the environment for WebView
    hr = CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(nullptr, buffTmp, nullptr,
        Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(
            [hWnd](HRESULT result, ICoreWebView2Environment* env) -> HRESULT 
            {
                HRESULT hr2;

                // Create a CoreWebView2Controller and get the associated CoreWebView2 whose parent is the main window hWnd
                hr2 = env->CreateCoreWebView2Controller(hWnd, 
                    Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler>(
                    [hWnd](HRESULT result, ICoreWebView2Controller* controller) -> HRESULT
                    {
                        HRESULT hr;

                        MessageBox(
                            NULL, L"ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler was called", 
                                                        L"Loaded_MsgBox",
                            MB_OK);

                        //Other code
                        ....

                        return S_OK;
                    }).Get());


                if(FAILED(hr2))
                {
                    WCHAR buff[256] = {};
                    StringCchPrintf(buff, _countof(buff), L"ERROR: (0x%x) CreateCoreWebView2Controller", hr2);
                    MessageBox(NULL, buff, L"ERROR", MB_ICONERROR);
                }


                return S_OK;
            }).Get());


    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        StringCchPrintf(buff, _countof(buff), L"ERROR: (0x%x) CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions", hr);
        MessageBox(NULL, buff, L"ERROR", MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    return hr;
}

The env->CreateCoreWebView2Controller call succeeds, but the ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler callback is never invoked (or my "Loaded_MsgBox" is never shown), so the HWND for the WebView2 remains blank.
There seems to be no error messages or anything that I can find.
Moreover, when I close the process, this also causes a crash somewhere in the destructor in the EmbeddedBrowserWebView.dll.
The WebView2 itself is so huge, I don't even know where to begin approaching this. Plus finding something that is never called is always hard.
Anyone who is familiar with the WebView2, do you have any idea how to make it work from the secure desktop?

WebView2 is not supported when running as a SYSTEM service.
MSFT representative answers:

Not currently supported. We've reached out to the credential provider folks for more details on these scenarios, but have yet to hear back from them.


After talking about all the risks and intended features, we have unfortunately decided not to support this use case at all.

There is a specific browser flag "allow-run-as-system" that allows to run WebView2 as a SYSTEM service in a logged on user session:



Flag
Description




allow-run-as-system
By default, the Edge WebView browser exits if launched as System (launching as System is not recommended). This flag bypasses that check, so that even if the Edge WebView browser is launched as System, the Edge WebView browser doesn't exit.



But, the same representative was saying that flag is not officially supported:

Due to security concerns, we are not planning to add official support for that flag, and recommend you don't use it.


It's funny that they say this, because Google are using it in their "Google Credential Provider".

So how do you enable it? Like this: auto options = Microsoft::WRL::Make<CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions>(); wil::unique_cotaskmem_string targetVersion; hr = options->put_AdditionalBrowserArguments(L"allow-run-as-system");? Because this doesn't seem to change anything.

Oh, forgot to say - and then by using options as the 3rd argument for the CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions call like I showed in my OP.

try put_AdditionalBrowserArguments(L"--allow-run-as-system");

@jls28: same. That makes no difference

It does not work on the login screen. It requires a logged on user.

@3CxEZiVlQ still makes no difference. My guess is that they are blocking it on purpose. The OP in that github thread notes that if he uses an older version of WebView, it works. Is there a way to specify which version of WebView I want to use?
